# CSS media queries in lotus notes client

Tags: css, media-queries, xpages, lotus-notes

So, well, we have an XPage application which works very well on all the browsers including the internal notes browser. Since, our target audience is both the desktop/mobile users we have designed a responsive layout using css media queries which works well on browsers, however, we just found out that when it runs as a notes application, it doesn't respect the media queries. It works as if there were no media queries (For eg. even the mobile specific items are shown on desktop). Any suggestions here to get it working? We are far way through and removing media queries would be kind of a last alternative.

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I never used media queries before and I am not sure what is involved, but in other projects (like JSF) when I was trying to get information on the user's device, I was sometimes getting null or unknown.  Is this a case that you are looking into?  (if that is even a possibility with media-queries)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the reason is that your Notes browser is rendering as IE.  IE doesn't support media queries up through IE 8.

IE is the default, try changing the internal browser to Firefox.  See this link for instructions.
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21268588

Comment: Steve, XPages in the Notes client uses XULRunner and not IE. Your explanation of unsupported media queries might still be the case for the specific version of XULRunner being used, though.